# How to access $root in the boot files with Quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am newbie with quasar.

I am using quasar 1.xx and Vue 2.
I need to use '$root' in a boot file, to emit a event.

All my pages are using: this.$root.on('event', somefunction).

My problem is '$root' is showing as undefined in boot files.

Is possible I use $root in boot files?

My sample code is something as:

```
import { Notify } from 'quasar'

export default ({ Vue, router }) => {

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(Vue.$root) --> results undefined
    Vue.$root.$emit('ChangingPage', true)

    if (!token) {
        if (to.fullPath !== '/login' && !to.query.tokenSetup) {
          Notify.create({
            message: 'Necessário realizar login',
            position: 'top',
          })
          next({ name: 'login' })
        } else {
          next()
        }
      } else {
        next()
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: I did. There is no root

Comment: oh right I need to read better sorry, I'm going to delete my comments, they are unnecessary